# Subgradient at the boundary of a closed set

Tags: convex-analysis, subgradient

Suppose I have the convex function $f(x) = |x|$ over the domain $x \in [-1,1]$, and I wish to find the subgradient.

It is easy to find the subgradient in the interior of the domain. At the boundaries, I can see that $\partial{}f(-1) = \{-\infty,-1\}$, and $\partial{}f(1) = \{1,\infty\}$ by sketching the function. However, **I am not sure how to show this mathematically**, due to the discontinuity.

How can I prove this? Thanks!

Comment: Recall that a subdifferential is always convex, so $\partial f(1) = \{1, \infty\}$ can never ever happen. And $\infty \not\in \mathbb{R}$, so it is not a valid candidate for a subgradient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's calculate the subgradient $D_1$ at $x=1$.

Let's prove that $D_1 \subset [1,+\infty[$ : Let $c \in D_1$, then
 $f(0) - f(1) \geq c ( 0-1)$, so $-1 \geq -c$, hence $c \geq 1$.

Let's prove that $[1,+\infty[ \subset D_1$ : Let $ c\geq 1$, then

- $\forall x \in [0,1], f(x)-f(1) = x-1 \geq 1.(x-1)$
- $\forall x \in [-1,0], f(x)-f(1) = |x|-1 \geq -1 \geq 1.(x-1)$

So $\forall x \in [-1,1], f(x)-f(1) \geq 1.(x-1)$, hence $x\in D_1$

Edit : by the way, there is no discontinuity at $x=1$.

Comment: It depends on the point of view. You can view $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ or $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$. In the latter case you have a discontinuity. In my opinion, this latter point of view is more common in convex analysis, but this might be wrong.

Comment: @gerrw : he said that the domain of $f$ is $[-1,1]$, so it is the first possibility here, no point of view possible. If it was the second case ( by extending the function by $f(x) = +\infty$ outside $[-1,1]$ ), yes, in this case there would be a discontinuity at $x=1$.

Comment: I disagree. In convex analysis, the domain is the set where the function values are finite. So the function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$ still has domain $[-1,1]$.

Comment: @gerw : that's strange that a definition of the domain of a function in convex analysis would be different (and incompatible) with the definition of the domain of a function in general mathematics. And with a quick google search, what you seems to be talking about is called the *effective domain* of $f$, not the domain of $f$